# Write own exception in logger

Tags: java, exception, logging

Have method for insert elements in array.

```
  public boolean insertElementToSlot(Element element, int index) {
        checkArray(index);
        try {
            if (element != null && mas[index] == null) {
                mas[index] = element;
                return true;
            } else {
               throw  new ElementValidationException("Element.insertElementToSlot", device);
            }
        } catch (ElementValidationException d) {
            logger.log(Level.SEVERE, ""+d);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

And own exception class with method:

```
public ElementValidationException(String operation, Element element) {
        super("Element is not valid for operation" + checkOperation(operation));
        this.element = element;
    }
```

When testing method insertElementToSlot, I have error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Expected exception: com.inventory.exception.ElementValidationException
```

Why is the error related and how to solve it?

Comment: Do you have `expected` clause in `@Test`? If yes, remove that if you are not expecting the test to throw the exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a unit test which expects an exception, it has to be thrown out of the test.  It doesn't check that this exception is thrown anywhere in the code but caught.

NOTE: your exception isn't being used as an exception and could be replaced with a log message

Your code is basically the same as

```
public boolean insertElementToSlot(Element element, int index) {
    checkArray(index);
    if (element != null && mas[index] == null) {
          mas[index] = element;
          return true;
    }
    logger.log(Level.SEVERE, "some.package.ElementValidationException");
    return false;
}
```